# Выполнение нескольких потоков asynctask в цикле

Tags: java, потоки-данных, android, android-asynctask

Разрабатываю приложение в котором необходимо выполнить несколько потоков в цикле. Имеется 4 Spinner-а.Данные для каждого спиннера берутся из базы данных на сервере в в каждом отдельном поток AsyncTasc. Мне нужно сделать чтобы в первом спиннере при выборе пункта "Все" показывались результаты всех спиннеров. Для этого делаю несколько вложенных в друг друга циклов. Но при вызове в каждом цикле new example().execute() данные не успевают передаваться. При Debug-е данные показываются но при выполнении программы в обычном режиме нет. 
Как сделать чтобы выполнение кода выполнялось только после окончания выполнения AsyncTasc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

класс `AsyncTask` так же имеет метод [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) , который дожидается выполнения задачи , а затем возвращает ее результат , если преопределение `onPostExecute()` вам не подходит ([пример использования](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/151-urok-88-asynctask-itogovyj-rezultat-metod-get.html))

Так же это не совсем решение вашей проблемы , но если вы выполняете более одного потока параллельно , запускать их на выполнение следует через:

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Данное решение ускорит обработку фоновых задач , так как указывает запускать поток параллельно с уже запущенными . Дело в том , что с `API11` запуск потока через `execute()` ставит все следующие после первого потоки в очередь и они дожидаются окончания выполнения предыдущих , то есть задачи выполняются последовательно , а не параллельно.

Answer (score 2):

`onPostExecute()`. есть такой метод в асинктаске. Он выполняется на `UI` потоке. В него и положите код, который надо выполнить после операций с `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь переопределенным методом onPostExecute, который выполнится после выполнения задачи в потоке doInBackground

Comment: Но у меня цикл выполняется в UI потоке и в нужных местах этого цикла я вызываю  AsyncTask  c new example().execute;         Но проблема в том что у меня сложность в возврате результата работы асинхронной задачи в пользовательский интерфейс. Поскольку интерфейс не знает, когда асинхронный поток закончит работу, то код выполняется дальше

Comment: Как вариант в конструктор asynctask передайте спиннер, и в postexecute заполняйте его